# RegExp match one Word or Multiple Words in Quotes

Tags: regex

I need a RegExp which matches a word or multiple words in quotes.

[\w]* matches a word

"[\w\W&&[^"]]*" matches multiple words in quotes.

(btw, not sure why \w\W works, but not a simple . (which should match all characters)

So how do i combine these two regexp?

Answer (score 9):

Does `"[^"]+"` do what you want? (Match a double-quote, match one or more chars that are not double quotes, then match a second double-quote.)

Answer (score 7):

first of all thanks.

your answers really helped - but i noticed my question maybe wasn't clear enough.

Anyway, from your answers i ended up with this regexp:

> "[^"]+"|[\w]+

Which matches Words and Multiple Words in Quotes.

e.g.: what is "this thing"
will give 3 matches:
first match: what
second match: is
third match: "this thing"

Which is exactly what i needed. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 Much simpler ;) I did not get at first what you wanted, but I leave my answer for reference

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer:

```
"\s*((?:\w(?!\s+")+|\s(?!\s*"))+\w)\s*"
```

rather than `"[^"]+"` because `^"` matches everything, no just `\w` (**alphanumerical**) char `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

That way, you match only `\w` chars within quotes, without trailing spaces.

```
" ee eee e ee  "
```

gives you in group(1):

```
ee eee e ee
```

The negative look-ahead `(?!\s+")` are here to make sure I do not include the last spaces before the double quote;